# Unstable MLP's accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm building an MLP for a classification problem. The number of output classes is 8 and my input data consist of 81 columns of binary features and in total 2416 data points.

So far my NN was 3 hidden layers with 400, 300 and 200 nodes respectively and the learning rate is set to 0.0001.

For training I wanted to implement batches with the following code:

```
number_of_examples = X_train.shape[0]
batch_size = 60
n_epochs = 10000
number_of_batches = X_train.shape[0] // batch_size

with tf.Session() as sess:    
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for i in range(number_of_batches):

            batch_start = (i - epoch) * batch_size % number_of_examples
            batch_stop = (i - epoch + 1) * batch_size % number_of_examples

            if (batch_stop < batch_start):
                batch_stop = number_of_examples
                X_batch = X_train[batch_start:number_of_examples, :]
                y_batch = y_train[batch_start:number_of_examples]

                data = np.column_stack((X_train, y_train))
                np.random.shuffle(data)
                X_train = data[:, :81]
                y_train = data[:, 81]

            else:
                X_batch = X_train[batch_start:batch_stop, :]
                y_batch = y_train[batch_start:batch_stop]

            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict = {X: X_train, y: y_train})

        accuracy_val, loss_val, accuracy_summary_str, loss_summary_str = sess.run([accuracy, loss, accuracy_summary, loss_summary], feed_dict={X: X_batch y: y_batch})
        acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict = {X: X_test, y: y_test})
```

When I executed the code I saw that the train accuracy was going up and down. At first I thought to decrease the learning rate in case it was too big for gradient descent to converge to the minimum. The accuracy kept on going up and down and also the learning was very slow (after 200 iterations the accuracy was between 30% and 35%).

I then removed all the batches implementation and used the whole dataset in hope that I can isolate the problem but the problem remained. 
The code without batches is:

```
number_of_examples = X_train.shape[0]
batch_size = 60
n_epochs = 10000
number_of_batches = X_train.shape[0] // batch_size

with tf.Session() as sess:    
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):

        sess.run(training_op, feed_dict = {X: X_train, y: y_train})

    accuracy_val, loss_val, accuracy_summary_str, loss_summary_str = sess.run([accuracy, loss, accuracy_summary, loss_summary], feed_dict={X: X_train, y: y_train})
    acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict = {X: X_test, y: y_test})
```

At this point I'm quite confused about what is going wrong. It is not the poor performance that troubles  me at this point but the unstable behavior of accuracy. 
Just to be complete I use ReLu as an activation function on the hidden layers and softmax on the output. The loss function is the cross entropy.